# Implement Dart workflow in Travis CI to deploy in Firebase

Tags: dart, travis-ci, angular-dart, firebase-hosting, dart-html

I'm new to both Firebase and Travis CI. Done some home work with Dart for sometime.

I'm trying to implement Travis CI for building my Angular Dart Project and deploying to Firebase.

It is going through the build and test fine, and while deploying i'm getting the below message.

**Error**: Specified public directory does not exist, can't deploy hosting

I have chosen build/web as my public directory while creating the firebase.json file. Seems like build directory is a different one in Travis CI.

What is the build directory?
Can i see some build files done in Travis CI for my project?
If so how?

Below is my GitHut Repository which i'm trying to automate the workflow.

**Git Hub**: https://github.com/Harikrishnadhas/siththargnaanaalayam

And Travis CI Build page shows the error here.

**Travis CI** : https://travis-ci.org/Harikrishnadhas/siththargnaanaalayam/builds/255561107

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer to my question below

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8131

Currently Travis Doesn't build the dart project, hence script for same has to be added.